# How to redirect the web page in flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

I have a button control ....i need another web page to be redirected while clicking that button .... how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [`navigateToURL()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()) function.